# Making a method unavailable in a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, nsobject

Let's say I'm creating a protocol with a custom initializer in it that I want some of my model objects to conform to.

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
- (instancetype)initWithContext:(Context *)context;
@end
```

In doing this, I also want to make `-[NSObject init]` unavailable. The way I've accomplished that in the past is by declaring something like this in the header:

`- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;`

or:

`- (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("Use -initWithContext:")));`

Is there a way to include something like the above in a protocol, so that any class conforming to this protocol will have their default initialization methods be unavailable?

To be explicit, I'm wondering if something like the following is valid:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
- (instancetype)initWithContext:(Context *)context;
- (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("Use -initWithContext:")));
@end
```

Comment: What you have written works and shows errors when trying to call `init` on any class implementing that protocol. Did you have a problem with this, or did you not try it for yourself first?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a protocol. Why don't you tell us what you want to achieve. I am positive that there is a better way of achieving the same goal.

Comment: Did you try by using category and overriding the method ?